# Assigning a string value to a variable of type NUMBER in pl/sql procedure not throwing any error

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have started working on pl/sql recently. So still not very clear with the concepts. I am a writing a Stored procedure which has some input values.
using thses input values  as keys,i  create a cursor.

After this  i iterate through the cursor output , and call insert statement for each row fetched.
before calling the insert, i am doing few data manipulations.

1. Splitting a String '4564:0:75556'  considering : as the delimiter.
   For this i am using SUBSTR and INSTR functions

My actual question starts here.
The output of SUBSTR will be a string value. i am assigning this value to a variable of type NUMBER which i declared in the proc.

I was expecting  an error while compiling this proc  or atleast when i test it.

Strangely i didnt get any error, the proc works fine.

is this the expected behaviour?

Can we assign a string value to variable of type NUMBER?
in my proc i am assignin output of SUBSTR to variables d_c1_subscr_no, d_c1_account_no, d_c1_subscr_no_resets NUMBER

My Stored proc:

```
         CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P4_UPDATE_BILL_PERIOD_BULK(oldperiod IN      VARCHAR,
                                                   newperiod IN VARCHAR,
                                                   accountno IN VARCHAR) IS
    d_c1_subscr_no        NUMBER;
    d_c1_account_no       NUMBER;
    d_c1_subscr_no_resets NUMBER;
    d_first_occ           NUMBER;
    d_second_occ          NUMBER;

     CURSOR c1_active_subs IS
     select ciem.external_id      as occ_ext_id,
       ciem.subscr_no        as fx_subscr_no,
       ciem.subscr_no_resets as fx_subscr_no_resets
     from customer_id_equip_map ciem, service s
    where ciem.subscr_no = s.subscr_no
     AND s.parent_account_no = to_number(accountno)
     AND ciem.subscr_no_resets = s.subscr_no_resets
     AND ciem.external_id_type = 6
      AND ciem.active_date < SYSDATE
     AND (ciem.inactive_date is null or ciem.inactive_date > SYSDATE);

    d_subscriber c1_active_subs%ROWTYPE;

      BEGIN

     OPEN c1_active_subs;
    LOOP
     FETCH c1_active_subs
          into d_subscriber;
            EXIT WHEN c1_active_subs%NOTFOUND;

        IF c1_active_subs%FOUND THEN
         d_first_occ  := INSTR(d_subscriber.occ_ext_id, ':', 1, 1);
                d_second_occ := INSTR(d_subscriber.occ_ext_id, ':', 1, 2);

            d_c1_subscr_no        := SUBSTR(d_subscriber.occ_ext_id,
                                  1,
                                  d_first_occ - 1);
           d_c1_subscr_no_resets := SUBSTR(d_subscriber.occ_ext_id,
                                  d_first_occ + 1,
                                  d_second_occ - d_first_occ - 1);
           d_c1_account_no       := SUBSTR(d_subscriber.occ_ext_id,
                                  d_second_occ + 1);

              INSERT INTO P4_BULK_DATA
            (BATCH_ID, STATUS, ARG1, ARG2, ARG3, ARG4, ARG5, ARG6, ARG7, ARG8)
            VALUES
              (10300,
        0,
         accountno,
       d_subscriber.fx_subscr_no,
          d_subscriber.fx_subscr_no_resets,
         d_c1_account_no,
         d_c1_subscr_no,
        d_c1_subscr_no_resets,
        oldperiod,
         newperiod);

         END IF;

      END LOOP;
      CLOSE c1_active_subs;

    END;
```

Comment: implicit conversion varchar2 -> number
[link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/datatypes.htm#BABJHGJD)

Answer (score 2):

Oracle database will normally conduct implicit conversions between many data types. As clarified in the link provided in the comment, Oracle implicitly converts from VARCHAR2 to NUMBER and vise versa. That said, it is always not recommended approach to rely on Oracle implicit conversions. It is always better to use the rich library of conversion functions provided by Oracle. For example:

- *Using the concatenation operator (||) to concatenate a string and an arithmetic expression can produce an error, which you can prevent by using the TO_CHAR function to convert the arithmetic expression to a string before concatenation*
- *Relying on language settings in the database for the format of a DATE value can produce unexpected results, which you can prevent by using the TO_CHAR function and specifying the format that you want*